# Sign In on Exchange Online EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

Which is the correct way to perform a sign in on O365 Exchange in order to use EWS?. I know that exists ADAL to perform authentication against O365, but since the code it's highly tied with the tenant ADAL is not a solution for my problem.

I'm developing an iOS App that needs to interact with Exchange (O365) and I'm unable to perform the authentication correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Exchange Web Services in Office 365, you can either use [Basic authentication or OAuth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626019(v=exchg.150).aspx). OAuth (which I think is what you mean by ADAL) is the recommended method. It's not tied to a tenant, but it does require that you register your application in a tenant (can be your own [developer tenant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment)) to get a client ID.

Comment: Thank you Jason. Your are right regarding ADAL, it uses OAuth and it's the recommended way to authenticate with O365. You are also right when you say that ADAL is not bound to a particular tenant, but the point here is that you must register the application inside Azure AD to obtain the ClientID. That's the reason because I said "bound to tenant". If you want to authenticate you App against a different tenant you must ask the user for authorisation using Common Consent Framework (if I'm not wrong). The drawback to this point is that granting consent to external users is not enabled by default